# How does the program knows the array goes up to 10?

Tags: c#, arrays

I have a problem with this task:

> Write a C# program which will accept a list of integers and checks how
>   many integers are needed to complete the range. For example [1, 3, 4,
>   7, 9], between 1-9 -> 2, 5, 6, 8 are not present in the list. So
>   output will be 4.

Here is the code to that task:

```
public class Example
{
    public static int consecutive_array(int[] input_Array)
    {
        Array.Sort(input_Array);
        int ctr = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < input_Array.Length - 1; i++)
        {
            ctr += input_Array[i + 1] - input_Array[i] - 1;
        }
        return ctr;
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(consecutive_array(new int[] { 1, 3, 5, 6, 9 }));
        Console.WriteLine(consecutive_array(new int[] { 0, 10 }));
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

---

My question is, how does the program know that the array goes from 0 to 9. We have defined just the Length of the Array.

Comment: *"how does the program know that the array goes from 0 to 9"* Which array? One has the range 1..9 and the other has the range 0..10. The range is simply maximum value minus minimum value.

Comment: this one goes to 11

Comment: So what _exactly_ is the question? Do you want an explanation of the code?

Comment: If so, the best practice is to debug step-by-step, and you'll understand what's happening.

Comment: The program sorts the array first, then loops through each item (except the last), subtracts it from the value of the next item, subtracts `1` from that, and adds it to the `ctr` result. So on the first iteration it will do: `ctr += 3 - 1 - 1` (which is the same as `ctr = ctr + 1;`). In other words, it keeps track of the difference between each number (minus one, since sequential numbers will have a difference of `1`) so that in the end you have the total difference representing the missing numbers.

Comment: `3 - 1 - 1 =` **`1`**, `5 - 3 - 1 =` **`1`**, `6 - 5 - 1 = 0`, `9 - 6 - 1 = 2`, and finally, `1 + 1 + 0 + 2 = 4`, which is the output.

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear what is your question. Since you completed the assignment, you ought to understand at least minimally how the code works. If you did not write the code, then perhaps you should ask the person you copied it from. If that is not an option, then step through/debug the code.

To solve the problem, I'd do it slightly differently:

You know that the length *should* be the difference between the max & min values, and you know how long the length *is*, so this should be simple arithmetic algorithm to determine the difference between the length of the `input_Array` and the length it *would* be if it was sequentially full:

```
    public static int consecutive_array(int[] input_Array)
    {
        // we know the array length SHOULD be ==( max - min + 1)
        Array.Sort(input_Array);
        int fullLength = (input_Array[input_Array.Count()-1] - input_Array[0] + 1);
        return (fullLength - input_Array.Length);
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

You are subtracting 1 from the length of the array and using a less than operator. This will effectively cut it off 1 item before the end.

Comment: It won't; the code's using `input_array[i + 1]` inside the loop.

Comment: That's by design since they're referencing index `i + 1` inside the loop...